# Why can't Ubuntu 20.04 server find internet URLs?

Tags: networking, server, internet, dns

**SYSTEM**

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server on an old desktop: let's call it "**UServer**". This will provide a place to store routine backups of 2 network-attached Windows computers, which I will call **WDesktop** and **WLaptop**; and also act as a music media server. There is a network-attached Logitech Squeezebox (**LSB**), for which **UServer** hosts the music library and the Logitech Media Server (LMS) app.

**MAIN PROBLEM**

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 three times before getting things set up the way I wanted. I was able to do multiple updates and set up several applications. But at some point, **UServer** stopped communicating with the Internet! It must be something I did, but I have not been able to figure out what. Since then, I have not been able to perform any updates to the installed software and LMS cannot access `mysqueezebox.com`. **LSB** can stream music files from the music library but then it is unable to stream radio from `mysqueezebox.com`, presumably because **UServer** cannot reach it. **LSB** can be reset to stream radio directly from `mysqueezebox.com` but then LMS running on **UServer** cannot find **LSB** on the LAN!

I have multiple devices attached to my LAN and they are all able to communicate with the outside world successfully. These devices include: **WDesktop**, **WLaptop** and **LSB**. In addition I have an old Sony laptop on which I have recently installed Ubuntu 21.10 (which I will call **ULaptop**). **WLaptop** communicates with the router using wi-fi. **WDesktop**, **ULaptop** and **LSB** all use ethernet, along with **UServer**. **UServer** and **LSB** are both set up with static IPs. My internet gateway is a standalone router (let’s call it **Router**) which serves all devices on a 10.0.0.x subnet, and it is connected to a separate modem using DHCP at 192.168.1.x.

**DIAGNOSTICS**

I am afraid I have limited understanding of network protocols. I have enabled *ufw* and created rules to allow access through the firewall to various ports for different protocols. Possibly there is something here that I’ve missed. I have tried disabling *ufw* to see if that fixed the problem but it did not make any obvious difference. Within the LAN, **UServer** is able to communicate with other devices, though not everything is visible on the Windows side, and not all devices can see **UServer**. Some of this may be Windows WORKGROUP issues that I have not yet resolved.

Here are some possibly useful outputs as reported by **UServer**:

```
$ ifconfig   [PARTIAL – note I am actually using two NICS: enp9s0 uses static IP and enp10s0 using DHCP]  

enp10s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  
        inet 10.0.0.25  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255  
        ether 00:24:8c:53:3d:d9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)  
        RX packets 32254448  bytes 43036469663 (43.0 GB)  
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0  
        TX packets 461772  bytes 97565110 (97.5 MB)  
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0  
  
enp9s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  
        inet 10.0.0.200  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255  
        ether 00:24:8c:53:3b:e8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)  
        RX packets 596538610  bytes 889898342859 (889.8 GB)  
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0  
        TX packets 308356174  bytes 19271733540 (19.2 GB)  
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536  
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0  
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)  
        RX packets 66067  bytes 8023177 (8.0 MB)  
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0  
        TX packets 66067  bytes 8023177 (8.0 MB)  
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0  

$ route -n  
Kernel IP routing table  
Destination   Gateway       Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  
0.0.0.0       10.0.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp9s0  
0.0.0.0       10.0.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp10s0  
10.0.0.0      0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp9s0  
10.0.0.0      0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp10s0  
10.0.0.1      0.0.0.0       255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp10s0  
172.17.0.0    0.0.0.0       255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

I can use *ssh* to log into **UServer** from **WDesktop** or from **ULaptop** using david@UServer or from **WLaptop** using david@10.0.0.200.

From **UServer**, I can *ping* **LSB**, **ULaptop** and **WLaptop** but I cannot reach **WDesktop** (either by hostname or even by using its IP address!). From **UServer**, I can also *ping* **Router**, but I cannot *ping* any outside URLs such as `google.com` or `8.8.8.8` or `mysqueezebox.com`. E.g., with

```
$ ping www.google.com
```

I get “Destination Host Unreachable”

Interestingly though, **UServer** does seem to know IP addresses of these external URLs. Could these be stored on a local DNS (from the time when I had Internet access working)?

I can use **UServer** to *ssh* into other devices, notably **LSB**. Then from **LSB** I can *ping* `mysqueezebox.com` and `google.com` successfully --- which I think demonstrates that there’s nothing wrong with my Internet connectivity! From **LSB** I can also *ping* back to **UServer** and other network-attached devices but only by using their IP addresses. I guess **LSB** is running a stripped-down version of Linux and doesn’t have the tools needed to identify hosts by name?

**APACHE 2**

Early on I decided to try to install Apache, thinking that one day I might want to serve data or info from **UServer** over www. I was able to do this successfully, but around the same time that I lost Internet connectivity, Apache 2 stopped delivering the default landing page. That is, any attempt to access `http://UServer`  returns “This site can’t be reached” in my browser. However, running

```
$ sudo systemctl status apache2
```

indicates that Apache 2 is loaded and functional.

**SUMMARY**

Clearly something is not quite right in the network configuration for **UServer**, which is causing it to be unable to access external URLs. I have messed with several files and while I have attempted to document when I made changes and why (i.e., because I found something that looked promising on a webpage somewhere), I cannot recall all of the things I’ve tried. Notably, I have edited `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`.  E.g.,

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces  
; DP 20220223: Created and edited this file following recommendations at:  
; https://askubuntu.com/questions/592840/ubuntu-server-cannot-access-internet-however-can-use-ssh  

; This file describes the network interfaces available on your system  
; and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).  

; The loopback network interface  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback  
  
; The primary network interface  
; auto eth0  
auto enp9s0  
  
iface enp9s0 inet static  
    address 10.0.0.200  
    netmask 255.255.255.0  
    gateway 10.0.0.1  
    dns-nameservers 10.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 4.4.4.4 dns1-2.registrar-servers.com
```

I have not figured out whether either of `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` was having any effect! Which network configuration takes precedence?

I have also edited `/etc/sysctl.conf` and `/etc/samba/smb.conf` a few times. (The latter was to try to make **UServer** and its shares visible to other machines on the LAN but that wouldn’t affect **UServer**’s access to the Internet would it?)

======================

```
$ sudo iptables -xvnL  
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 329 packets, 53404 bytes)  
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination  

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)  
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination  
       0        0 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  
       0        0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED  
       0        0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 257 packets, 26208 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination  

Chain DOCKER (1 references)  
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination  

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)  
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination  
       0        0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)  
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination  
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)  
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination  
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

============================

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml  
; This is the network config written by 'subiquity'  
; Modified DP 2022-01-22  
; Modified DP 2022-03-02  
; Modified DP 2022-03-15 Following  
;  askubuntu.com/questions/1233934/no-internet-connection-after-ubuntu-server-20-04-install-ifconfig-not-available  


network:  
  version: 2  
;  renderer: NetworkManager  
  renderer: networkd  
  ethernets:  
    enp10s0:  
      dhcp4: true  
    enp9s0:  
      dhcp4: false  
      addresses: [10.0.0.200/24]  
;      gateway4: 192.168.1.254  
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1  
      nameservers:  
;          addresses: [192.168.1.254, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]  
;          addresses: [10.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]  
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 10.0.0.1]
```

=======================================================

```
$ ip route  
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp9s0 proto static  
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp10s0 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.25 metric 100  
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp9s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.200  
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp10s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.25  
10.0.0.1 dev enp10s0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.25 metric 100  
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

========================================================

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135273/discussion-on-question-by-david-p-why-cant-ubuntu-20-04-server-find-internet-ur).

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this question seems to be to:

(1) Disable `/etc/network/interfaces` as this is now considered obsolete.

(2) Use `/etc/netplan` instead.

(3) Change a single line (or even a single word) in `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`.

Instead of using:

`renderer: networkd`

use:

`renderer: NetworkManager`

After making this change, run the following commands:

`$ sudo netplan generate`
`$ sudo netplan apply`

If this has solved the problem, it will become possible to access URLs "beyond the router". E.g.:

```
$ ping google.com  
PING google.com (142.250.69.206) 56(84) bytes of data.  
64 bytes from sea30s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.69.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=14.9 ms  
64 bytes from sea30s08-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.69.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=14.2 ms  
^C  
--- google.com ping statistics ---  
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5009ms  
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.223/14.698/14.870/0.215 ms
```